# ASP MVC3 adding primary key that doesn't exist in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, edmx

I am trying to add a table by the name of `AgentId` to my ASP MVC site. This table does not have a primary key, but it does use a foreign key to map it to another table, `BankMasterList`. One agent may work with a number of banks, so an Agent ID will generally wind up appearing more than once in the `AgentId` table.

Each time I try this, however, Visual Studio will classify the first column of the table `AgentId` (the column name happens to be the same name as the table: `AgentId`) as a primary key.

If I remove the primary key designation and hit save/build, Visual Studio then proceeds to remove each and every `.cs` model contained in the `.tt`Text Templating Transformation Toolkit file. Obviously, the project explodes after this since all the controllers now are using invalid namespaces.

Can anyone offer any suggestions or an explanation as to what is going on?

Here is a screen shot from SQL Server Management Studio of the `AgentId` table:

[image]

And here is the table depicted in the `.edmx` file in the Visual Studio project:

[image]

Comment: AgentId is *not* the primary key?

Comment: The EDMX designer will pick **all non-nullable columns** as primary key if it cannot find an actual primary key on a table. A table **should always have** a primary key, though!

Comment: @Robert: `AgentId` (column name) is not the primary key.

Comment: @marc: Since we will have repeating Agent Ids and Bank Ids we left the table without a primary key, although this project is still in the proof-of-concept phase. What should I do about the project removing all the current models when I remove the primary key from the `AgentId` column?

Comment: There ought to be a proper primary key on any *real* table. Always. If neither `AgentID` nor `ID` (nor the combination of the two) can be the primary key - then you ought to add a separate surrogate column (`INT IDENTITY`) as primary key.

Comment: Call it `AgentBankID`.

Comment: @marc: Combining `AgentId` and `ID` into a primary key has solved the problem. Would you mind posting an answer with, if possible, an explanation of why the model `.cs` files are removed when I save the table w/o a primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EDMX designer will pick **all non-nullable columns** of your table as "substitute" primary key if it cannot find an actual primary key on a table.

A "real" table (not just temporary, for e.g. bulk load) should **always** have a primary key, though! If neither `AgentID` nor `ID` can be used as primary key on their own, I would try to see if the combination of the two (`AgentID, ID`) can be your the primary key; and if that doesn't work either, then I'd recommend to add a separate surrogate column (`INT IDENTITY`) as primary key. You should always be able to uniquely and reliably identify each and every single row of any of your tables.